# Which is the meaning of "palm-to-forehand"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I am reading a science-fiction short story and I met this sentence that I can't understand.[image] You can read the whole sentence in the attached file.

"Palm-to-forehand"

What does it means? Think you everybody for your help.

Andrea, Rome, Italy

Comment: You do have a typo in your question. "Forehand" is misspelled.  "Palm-to-forehead", as in the example, is a word description for a common "non-verbal" gesture that conveys "utter/sad/unbelievable amazement". It also expresses the question - What were you thinking?

Comment: So sorry for my misunderstanding. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: It's when you dope-slap yourself.

Comment: In this case, the original text is arguably wrong at a stylistic level. Unless being used as an adjective (which it isn't) I would remove the hyphens and say *Palm to forehead, buddy*.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very useful comment for me!